# How to programmatically determine default applications in linux

Tags: python, linux, shell, default-programs

In linux, how can I determine the default text editor, terminal, etc?

does it vary by distro?

Comment: Ok so looks like the system uses a file called defaults.list. So finding out which defaults.list the system is using should solve this. If anyone has any tips, do go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the notion of **default** editor or terminal makes sense. For the editor, there is the convention of using `$EDITOR` when it is defined.

On Debian and related (e.g. Ubuntu, Mint) you have paths like `/usr/bin/editor` and `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator` symlinked (via symlinks in `/etc/alternatives/`) to some system default.

See also [Dacav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764283/841108)

Answer (score 3):

I accessed the list while ago programatically in a rather ugly manner and I'm sure its not the best way. The options are stored in a file called defaults.list (I think this is generally the case).  The location is less general I think it in /usr/share/applications/ on my ubuntu system although it does appear elsewhere I think. I then treated it as a text file.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution order is `$EDITOR` -> `editor` -> some predefined list of console editors. On Debian/Ubuntu, `sensible-editor` (and `sensible-browser` and `sensible-pager`) will do the lookup for you, including looking at the right environment variables. Similar variables are `$PAGER`, `$SHELL`, `$BROWSER`. To look up a file association, you can use `xdg-open`.

Answer (score 1):

Per-user environment variables tells you that.

- $EDITOR gives you the command to be launched as text editor;
- $BROWSER gives you the browser
- $PAGER gives you the pager (ex. more or less).

This however is valid for command line softwares, while usually desktop environments use their own (internal) variables.

Also in python you can read the environment variables using `os.getenv`.

Comment: so i should i be able to (in shell) echo $EDITOR to view what it is?
I just tried and it just gave me a blank line

Comment: Indeed yes. It's definition is not compulsory. I guess in case it's not present it defaults on some distro-based value. I don't know how to get it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This works in ubuntu/gnome:

```
>>> query_lines = subprocess.check_output(['update-alternatives',
                                           '--query',
                                           'gnome-text-editor']).split('\n')
>>> bestlist = filter(lambda l: 'Best' in l, query_lines)
>>> bestlist[0].split()[1]
'/usr/bin/gedit'
```

If not on gnome, you could at least get the command-line editor:

```
>>> query_lines = subprocess.check_output(['update-alternatives',
...                                        '--query',
...                                        'editor']).split('\n')
>>> bestlist = filter(lambda l: 'Best' in l, query_lines)
>>> bestlist[0].split()[1]
'/bin/nano'
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking hint from @bowler's answer, and purely bash:

```
editor=$(grep "text/plain" -r -i -I /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | awk -F';' '{print $1}' | awk -F'.desktop' '{print $1}' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
```